# How to squeeze a list of numpy arrays into an existing array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Consider the following snippet:

```
import numpy as np

pos = np.array([1, 3, 4])
arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
vals = np.array([[-10,10], [-20,20], [99,66]])
```

I want to squeeze the elements of `val` into `arr` in the indices specified by `pos`.
At the end, the desired result should be:

```
result = array([0, -10, 10, 1, 2, -20, 20, 3,  99, 66, 4, 5])
```

Comment: This looks like the same question as [this one](/q/77222723/16343464), how is it different? Is the other one resolved?

Comment: There are two differences: 1) In the mentioned question there is an explicit request on the `np.insert` function; 2) `vals` here is not a 1D array but a 2D array. The other question has been answered but unfortunately that answer won't cover this case.

Comment: keep in mind that  numpy arrays don't grow (except for a limited use of the `resize` method).  `insert` returns a new array, as does the masked method I demonstrated in your previous question. Other than `vals` being 2d, this isn't any different - just flatten/ravel to 1d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `vals` is a numpy array and you can ensure all insertions have the same lengths, an approach could be to [`repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) `pos` and [`insert`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) the flat version of `vals` (using [`ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html)):

```
out = np.insert(arr, np.repeat(pos, vals.shape[1]), vals.ravel())
```

Output:

```
array([  0, -10,  10,   1,   2, -20,  20,   3,  99,  66,   4,   5])
```

Comment: Very elegant answer. Thanks.

Comment: I accepted the answer, but I actually have two follow-up question (may be too broad though)1)  In this specific case, are there any drawbacks in re-assigning `arr` instead of using `out`, i.e.  `arr = np.insert(arr, ...)` ? 3) Would that be possible to use `flatten` instead or `ravel`?

Comment: 1) unless you needed the original object, no. Since `insert` returns a new array the operation is not in place anyway. 2) `flatten` always returns a copy, which can be more expensive.